# angularJs filter using ng-repeat and select

Tags: angularjs

I want to filter my table using **select** value. In my code below, using **input type=text...** filter works just fine. But i don't know how to filter using **select** value.

```
<div class="columns large-2-5">
    <select name="categorySelector"
            class="selectbox"
            ng-model="search"
            ng-options="category.name for category in categories">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.name">
    <table class="grid">
       <tbody ng-repeat="image in imageList | filter: { category: search.name }">
         <tr photolistsetting-Directive
            title="{{ image.name }}"
            ref="{{ image.url }}"
            category="{{ image.category }}">
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

select list is made of objects. Maybe i can't access an object property ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
  <select name="categorySelector"
        class="selectbox"
        ng-model="search.name"
        ng-options="category.name for category in categories">
    <option value="">Select Category</option>
</select>
```

Edit: Sorry I pointed out incorrect earlier.

Can you post "categories" and "imageList" array here?

Comment: it selects an object. if i use {{ search.name }} it prints an object. Any ideas how to refer to object property in filter ?

Comment: Have a look at this, its similar to your code and working: http://plnkr.co/edit/xf8UTpn2eBx6H1muMnfz?p=preview

Comment: accidentally moved one div out of scope. damn i'm fool. Your example is good. Thanks :)